# Solve $x^2 + 8 = 3^n$, where $x\in\mathbb N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

First of all, $n$ is even (find that out by trying to see what kind of remainders you can possibly get when dividing everything by 4). So $n=2m$, $m\in N$.

$ x^2 + 8 = 3^{2m} \Rightarrow x^2 - 1 = 3^{2m} - 9 \Rightarrow (x+1)(x-1) = (3^m + 3)(3^m - 3) \Rightarrow x$ is odd.

That's all I've tried so far. I'd like to get some help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for all possible solutions or any solution? $n = 2$, $x =1$ is one solution.  Not sure if any others exist.

Comment: Of course I'm looking for all the possible ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Now that you know $n$ is even, write $8=(3^{n/2}-x)(3^{n/2}+x)$. What are the possible factors of $8$? Which cases do we have, then?

Answer (score 4):

As $n=2m$, we have $x^2+9=(3^m)^2$, i.e. $8=(3^m+x)(3^m-x)$. Thus $x=\frac{a-b}2$ where $ab=8$ and $a\ge b$, i.e. $x\in\{\frac{8-1}2,\frac{4-2}2\}$ and finally $x=1$.

Comment: You have a nine there where you meant, perhaps, $8$?