# Find all $\{m,n\} ∈ \mathbb Z_+$, such that $m^2+8=3^n$

Tags: number-theory

Find all {m,n} ∈ Z+, such that m²+8=3ⁿ

My attempt:
n ∈ Z+
3ⁿ is odd 
m²+8 is odd
m² is odd 
m is odd
m=√3ⁿ-8
Since m>0, √3ⁿ-8>0 
Therefore 3ⁿ>8
n ≥ 2,
m ≥ 1, and is odd

Comment: $8=m^n-m^2=m^2(m^{n-2}-1).$ Then use unique factorization.

Comment: Why do you think $m^2+8$ is odd?  If $m$ is even then $m^2 + 8$ is even. If $m$ is odd then $m^2 + 8$ is odd.

Comment: Sorry I missed typed my question, it was supposed to be 3^n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve $x^2 + 8 = 3^n$, where $x\in\mathbb N$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609104/solve-x2-8-3n-where-x-in-mathbb-n) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24m%5E2%2B8%3D3%5En%24&p=1). There's also the AoPS thread [Find the numbers that satisfied the equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1717143p11094629).